# JS variable undefined in onclick event in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a small form on my page where a user can either search for availability at a specific hotel, or search for availability at all hotels:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Redirect() {
        if (searchAll) {
            document.getElementById("Hotel").value = "0";
        }

        return true;
    }
</script>

<form name="form1" action="search.asp" method="POST" id="form1"
    onsubmit="return Redirect()">

    <input type="hidden" id="Hotel" name="Hotel" value="<%= HotelID %>">

    <input id="btnHotelSearch" type="submit" name="btnHotelSearch"
        value="Search This Hotel" onclick="searchAll=false">
    <input id="btnHotelSearchAll" type="submit" name="btnHotelSearchAll"
        value="Search All Hotels" onclick="searchAll=true">
</form>
```

Whenever a button is pushed, I run some javascript to set the HotelID being passed. This works fine in Firefox. But in IE, whenever I push either button, I get a script error saying **'searchAll' is undefined**

What do I need to do to fix that?

Comment: This question got nothing to do with ASP.NET or classic ASP please learn to tag your questions better and with only *relevant* tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the `searchAll` variable outside of the `Redirect` function, so it's in the global scope and therefore accessible from the `Redirect` function, and your inline event handlers:

```
var searchAll;
function Redirect() {
    if (searchAll) {
        document.getElementById("Hotel").value = "0";
    }

    return true;
}
```